# Easy bitset I/O

Tags: c++, io, bitset

I'm writing a program that makes heavy use of `std::bitset`'s and occasionally needs to read/write these to file. `std::bitset` does overload the `<<` & `>>` operators, but using these will result in an ASCII encoded file (i.e. {0,1} = 1 byte), which is ~8x bigger than it would be if using a bit-for-bit encoding.

I've seen a few questions on Stack Overflow relating to this, such as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251403/binary-serialization-of-stdbitset), but it seems there is no standard or easy way to do `bitset` I/O. I therefore set about writing a general `bitset` I/O class that is able to easily read and write multiple `bitset`'s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>

template <std::size_t N>
class BitIo
{
public:

    void push_back(const std::bitset<N>& bs)
    {
        std::vector<Byte> result((N + 7) >> 3);
        for (int j = 0; j < int(N); ++j) {
            result[j >> 3] |= (bs[j] << (j & 7));
        }
        for (const Byte& byte : result) {
            bytes.push_back(byte);
        }
        num_bytes += NUM_BYTES_PER_BITSET;
    }

    std::bitset<N> pop_front()
    {
        std::bitset<N> result;
        for (int j = 0; j < int(N); ++j) {
            result[j] = ((bytes[(j >> 3) + offset] >> (j & 7)) & 1);
        }
        offset += NUM_BYTES_PER_BITSET;
        num_bytes -= NUM_BYTES_PER_BITSET;
        return result;
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return num_bytes < NUM_BYTES_PER_BITSET;
    }

    void clear()
    {
        bytes.clear();
        num_bytes = 0;
    }

    std::size_t size()
    {
        return num_bytes;
    }

private:

    using Byte = unsigned char;
    static constexpr std::size_t NUM_BYTES_PER_BITSET = N / 8;

    template <std::size_t T>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BitIo<T>& bio);
    template <std::size_t T>
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, BitIo<T>& bio);

    std::istream& read_file(std::istream& is)
    {
        bytes.clear();

        std::streampos current_pos, file_size;
        current_pos = is.tellg();
        is.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        file_size = is.tellg() - current_pos;
        is.seekg(current_pos, std::ios::beg);

        bytes.resize(file_size);
        is.read((char*) &bytes[0], file_size);

        num_bytes += file_size;

        return is;
    }

    std::vector<Byte> bytes;
    std::size_t offset = 0;
    std::size_t num_bytes = 0;
};

template <std::size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BitIo<N>& bio)
{
    for (const auto& byte : bio.bytes) {
        os << byte;
    }
    return os;
}

template <std::size_t N>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, BitIo<N>& bio)
{
    if(!is) {
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }
    bio.read_file(is);
    return is;
}
```

Here is an example usage:

```
std::ofstream bin_out("~/bf.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

BitIo<16> bio;

bio.push_back(std::bitset<16>("1001011010010110"));
bio.push_back(std::bitset<16>("0000000011111111"));
bio.push_back(std::bitset<16>("1111111100000000"));
bio.push_back(std::bitset<16>("0011001111001100"));

bin_out << bio;
bin_out.close(); // bf.bin is 8 bytes

std::ifstream bin_in("~/bf.bin", std::ios::binary);

BitIo<16> bio2;
bin_in >> bio2;

while (!bio2.empty()) {
    cout << bio2.pop_front() << endl; // Prints the 4 16-bit bitsets in correct order.
}
```

I'm looking for any performance optimisations and design improvements.

At the moment, only one file can be read, it might be nice to be able to read multiple files into a single object. If anyone can suggest a method for doing this without impacting performance that would be good!

Comment: Not the interface I would want. I would have liked to go:  `std::cout << BitIO(myBitset) << "\n";` for output or `std::cin >> BitIO(myBitset)` for input.

Comment: I don't see how that could work well when there are multiple `bitset`s involved.

Comment: That's another problem i have with this code. Buffering it up in a vector before printing makes the whole interface for using it terrible. If I already have multiple bitsets (lets say a vector (or any container)). The commented technique works beautifully with `std::copy()` and `std::ostream_iterator()`. If I have a single bitset I don't need to create a vector to print it like this technique uses.

Comment: `std::copy(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::ostream_iterator<BitIO>(std::cout));`

Comment: `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<BitIO>(file), std::istream_iterator<BitIO>(), std::back_inserter(data));`

Comment: See: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67350/easy-bit-io-very-simple-interface-works-up-to-n-64

Comment: It's not too much work to add a constructor that would give the option of using the class in the same way as your interface. I went with the buffering approach as I'm trying to write 2-4GBs worth of data to file, and I figured there would be some performance benefits to using a buffer (and not having the overhead of creating a bunch of objects).

Comment: Also my `bitset`s are much bigger than N=64 so I can't use your approach as is. You could extend your class to handle cases where N>64, but then you'd need to add a buffer.

Comment: No I would just print them out as a hex string and when reading them I would just loop over the text string and set the bits. Its still a much simpler solution than yours (it would only add five lines to my code to support n>64). There is no point in buffering as the stream already has a buffer built in.

Comment: You may want to look into using [`boost:dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#member-functions) instead of `std:bitset`. While it comes with the overhead of dynamic memory allocation, it allows you to insert and extract bits *block-wise* into/from iterators over an arbitrary `Block` type, e. g. `char` or `uintmax_t`, which you can easily transform and connect to an I/O stream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using an `std::vector` for temporary storage inside `push_back()`. This is a possible point of optimization, since the size of it is constant (`(N + 7) >> 3`). You could use an `std::array` in this case to make sure no dynamic memory is allocated. If you are concerned however that your `N` is going to be, in some cases, big enough to cause a stack overflow, then the `vector` would be indeed the best choice.

---

Appending the vectors inside `push_back()` can be simplified:

```
for (const Byte& byte : result) {
    bytes.push_back(byte);
}
```

You can use [`std::vector::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert):

```
bytes.insert(std::end(bytes), std::begin(result), std::end(result));
```

This is also more efficient, since `insert()` can take the difference between `begin` / `end` and `reserve()` the exact amount of memory that will be needed.

---

```
for (int j = 0; j < int(N); ++j)
```

This `int(N)` cast is silly. Declare `j` with `std::size_t` type.

Also, why are you keeping a separate byte count in `num_bytes` if the `bytes` vector has that same info in its `size()` method?

---

Avoid C-style casts:

```
is.read((char*) &bytes[0], file_size);
```

Change to:

```
is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&bytes[0]), file_size);
```

---

Methods that don't mutate member state are `const`:

```
bool empty() const;

std::size_t size() const;
```

Comment: Nice suggestions. The reason I'm keeping a byte count (`num_bytes`) and an offset into the `vector` (`offset`) is so I don't have to actually modify the underlying `vector`.

Comment: @Daniel, Oh I see, you are not removing data on `pop_back`. Okay.

Answer (score 2):

```
static constexpr std::size_t NUM_BYTES_PER_BITSET = N / 8;
```

I fear that by choosing this as NUM_BYTES_PER_BITSET you are underestimating the number of required bytes when N is not a multiple of 8. This is not an issue since you are using a vector, but when reading the offset may be wrong!