# Easy Bit IO. Very simple interface works up to N == 64

Tags: c++, io, bitset

After reading this question [Easy bitset I/O](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67012/easy-bitset-i-o). I wanted to see if there was a simpler way of doing it.

This is how I would define a way of outputting `std::bitset<N>` to the stream and reading it back in. It works perfectly with current containers.

#### BitIO.h

```
// Include guards deliberately not included for simplicity.

#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

template<int S>
class BitIO
{
    public:
    std::bitset<S>&     data;
    BitIO(std::bitset<S>& data)
        : data(data)
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, BitIO const& value)
    {
        // Currently using just an integer.
        //
        // But we could easily take this a step further and use hex.
        // and pad with 0 to get an exact width (that way we don't need a
        // trailing space).
        //
        // Using a fixed width means we may potentially waste space but can
        // be made to waste the least amount of space possible quite easily.
        //
        // Amount of wasted space would be (4 - (S % 4)) % 4

        return stream << value.data.to_ullong() << " ";
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, BitIO& value)
    {
        // As the current output uses a white space separated
        // unsigned long long it is easy to read it back in using the
        // normal `operator>>`
        //
        // Would be just as simple to convert this function to use
        // a fixed width format to mirror the output. 
        unsigned long long tmp;
        if (stream >> tmp)
        {
            value.data  = std::bitset<S>(tmp);
        }
        return stream;
    }
};
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "BitIO.h"
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::bitset<16> >    values { std::bitset<16>(1), std::bitset<16>(2), std::bitset<16>(255) };

    std::copy(std::begin(values), std::end(values), std::ostream_iterator<BitIO<16>>(std::cout));


    std::bitset<16>  data { 129 };
    std::cout << BitIO<16>(data);

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is relatively short and well-written, so I didn't find many nits to pick.  With that said, here's my review:

### Include all needed files

Since `std::ostream_iterator` is declared in `<iterator>` that should be among the includes in `main`:

```
#include <iterator>
```

### Use appropriate type for template parameter

The `std::bitset` template is defined as taking `std::size_t` rather than `int`, so it would make sense to define the `BitIO` template similarly:

```
template<std::size_t S>
class BitIO
{
    // ...
};
```

One can, of course, still abuse the interface by passing negative numbers but at least the user of the code is forewarned that they will be interpreted as `std::size_t` rather than as signed numbers.

### Consider implementing a `move` constructor

At the moment, this potential usage cannot compile:

```
std::cout << BitIO<16>(std::bitset<16>{ 99 });
```

It's easily fixed by adding this constructor:

```
BitIO(std::bitset<S>&& data)
    : data(data)
{}
```

### Maintain parallelism with existing practice

I was surprised to see spaces separating the outputs when none had been specified in the output `ostream_iterator`.  Although having the space is arguably useful, the choice of separator (if any) should be left up to the user of the template instead of being hardcoded in the `operator <<` function.  I'd omit the trailing space to allow usage like this:

```
std::copy(std::begin(values), std::end(values), 
        std::ostream_iterator<BitIO<16>>(std::cout,":"));
```

Comment: The constructor could take its value by const reference and still work (have not tried). But that would make the move constructor redundant.